# How to make detached head the original branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch. My local branch has 5 (m) commits which I have not pushed to remote. The same branch is 7 (n) commit ahead of me. Now what I want to do is remove my 5 (m) unnecessary commits and become same as what remote branch is.

What I tried so far :
1) I went to specific commit where I and remote were same.
2) then I pulled from remote branch. 
3) Now I and remote branch are same.
4) Now branch is called (HEAD detached from xxxxf)

How can I make (HEAD detached from xxxxf) branch the same as remote branch?

Comment: Have you tried to rebase on master?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forget about your changes and just set your local branch where the remote branch is:

`git checkout local-branch
git reset --hard the-remote/remote-branch`